# openCV:Trying to find black pixels in binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a monochrome BMP file of 1 bit depth.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrOsU.png

I am trying to find the location and number of black pixels in this image.

This is my code:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("/home/jordan/opencv/Test/edge_detection/img2.bmp",0);
cout<<"cols= "<<img.cols<<"row= "<<img.rows<<"\n";
int i,j,count=0;
for(i=0;i<=img.cols;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<=img.rows;j++)
{
int k=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
if(k==0)
{  
count++;
cout<<"col="<<i<<"row="<<j<<"k= "<< k<<"\t\n";
}
}
} 
cout<<"count="<<count<<"\n";
}
```

as can be seen in the following output i m getting lots of zeros on the row 195, which is not correct as per the above image. Please help me to solve this problem.

Output:

> clo=98row=69 k=0   clo=98row=195 k=0   clo=99row=69 k=0    clo=99row=195
>   k=0    clo=100row=69 k=0   clo=100row=195 k=0  clo=101row=69 k=0
>   clo=101row=195 k=0     clo=102row=69 k=0   clo=102row=195 k=0 
>   clo=103row=68 k=0  clo=103row=195 k=0  clo=104row=68 k=0
>   clo=104row=195 k=0     clo=105row=68 k=0   clo=105row=195 k=0 
>   clo=106row=68 k=0  clo=106row=195 k=0  clo=107row=68 k=0
>   clo=107row=195 k=0     clo=108row=68 k=0   clo=108row=195 k=0 
>   clo=109row=68 k=0  clo=109row=195 k=0  clo=110row=68 k=0
>   clo=110row=195 k=0     clo=111row=68 k=0   clo=111row=195 k=0 
>   clo=112row=68 k=0  clo=112row=195 k=0  clo=113row=68 k=0
>   clo=113row=195 k=0     clo=114row=68 k=0   clo=114row=195 k=0 
>   clo=115row=68 k=0  clo=115row=195 k=0  clo=116row=68 k=0
>   clo=116row=195 k=0     clo=117row=68 k=0   clo=117row=195 k=0 
>   clo=118row=68 k=0  clo=118row=195 k=0  clo=119row=68 k=0
>   clo=119row=195 k=0     clo=120row=68 k=0   clo=120row=195 k=0 
>   clo=121row=68 k=0  clo=121row=195 k=0  clo=122row=68 k=0
>   clo=122row=195 k=0     clo=123row=68 k=0   clo=123row=195 k=0 
>   clo=124row=68 k=0  clo=124row=195 k=0  clo=125row=68 k=0
>   clo=125row=195 k=0     clo=126row=68 k=0   clo=126row=195 k=0 
>   clo=127row=69 k=0  clo=127row=195 k=0  clo=128row=69 k=0
>   clo=128row=195 k=0     clo=129row=69 k=0   clo=129row=195 k=0 
>   clo=130row=69 k=0  clo=130row=195 k=0  clo=131row=69 k=0
>   clo=131row=195 k=0     clo=132row=69 k=0   clo=132row=195 k=0 
>   clo=133row=69 k=0  clo=133row=195 k=0  clo=134row=69 k=0
>   clo=134row=195 k=0     clo=135row=69 k=0   clo=135row=195 k=0 
>   clo=136row=69 k=0  clo=136row=195 k=0  clo=137row=70 k=0
>   clo=137row=195 k=0     clo=138row=70 k=0   clo=138row=195 k=0 
>   clo=139row=70 k=0  clo=139row=195 k=0  clo=140row=70 k=0
>   clo=140row=195 k=0     clo=141row=70 k=0   clo=141row=195 k=0 
>   clo=142row=70 k=0  clo=142row=195 k=0  clo=143row=70 k=0
>   clo=143row=195 k=0     clo=144row=71 k=0   clo=144row=195 k=0 
>   clo=145row=71 k=0  clo=145row=195 k=0  clo=146row=71 k=0
>   clo=146row=195 k=0     clo=147row=71 k=0   clo=147row=195 k=0 
>   clo=148row=71 k=0  clo=148row=195 k=0  clo=149row=72 k=0
>   clo=149row=195 k=0     clo=150row=72 k=0   clo=150row=195 k=0 
>   clo=151row=72 k=0  clo=151row=195 k=0  clo=152row=72 k=0
>   clo=152row=195 k=0     clo=153row=73 k=0   clo=153row=195 k=0 
>   clo=154row=73 k=0  clo=154row=195 k=0  clo=155row=73 k=0
>   clo=155row=195 k=0     clo=156row=73 k=0   clo=156row=195 k=0 
>   clo=157row=74 k=0  clo=157row=195 k=0  clo=158row=74 k=0
>   clo=158row=195 k=0     clo=159row=74 k=0   clo=159row=195 k=0 
>   clo=160row=74 k=0  clo=160row=195 k=0  clo=161row=75 k=0
>   clo=161row=195 k=0     clo=162row=75 k=0   clo=162row=195 k=0 
>   clo=163row=75 k=0  clo=163row=195 k=0  clo=164row=76 k=0
>   clo=164row=195 k=0     clo=165row=76 k=0   clo=165row=195 k=0 
>   clo=166row=76 k=0  clo=166row=195 k=0  clo=167row=76 k=0
>   clo=167row=195 k=0     clo=168row=77 k=0   clo=168row=195 k=0 
>   clo=169row=77 k=0  clo=169row=195 k=0  clo=170row=78 k=0
>   clo=170row=195 k=0     clo=171row=78 k=0   clo=171row=195 k=0 
>   clo=172row=78 k=0  clo=172row=195 k=0  clo=173row=79 k=0
>   clo=173row=195 k=0     clo=174row=79 k=0   clo=174row=195 k=0 
>   clo=175row=79 k=0  clo=175row=195 k=0  clo=176row=80 k=0
>   clo=176row=195 k=0     clo=177row=80 k=0   clo=177row=195 k=0 
>   clo=178row=81 k=0  clo=178row=195 k=0  clo=179row=81 k=0
>   clo=179row=195 k=0     clo=180row=82 k=0   clo=180row=195 k=0 
>   clo=181row=82 k=0  clo=181row=195 k=0  clo=182row=83 k=0
>   clo=182row=195 k=0     clo=183row=83 k=0   clo=183row=195 k=0 
>   clo=184row=83 k=0  clo=184row=195 k=0  clo=185row=84 k=0
>   clo=185row=195 k=0     clo=186row=84 k=0   clo=186row=195 k=0 
>   clo=187row=85 k=0  clo=187row=195 k=0  clo=188row=85 k=0
>   clo=188row=195 k=0     clo=189row=86 k=0   clo=189row=195 k=0 
>   clo=190row=86 k=0  clo=190row=195 k=0  clo=191row=87 k=0
>   clo=191row=195 k=0     clo=192row=88 k=0   clo=192row=195 k=0 
>   clo=193row=88 k=0  clo=193row=195 k=0  clo=194row=89 k=0
>   clo=194row=195 k=0     clo=195row=89 k=0   clo=195row=195 k=0 
>   clo=196row=90 k=0  clo=196row=195 k=0  clo=197row=91 k=0
>   clo=197row=195 k=0     clo=198row=91 k=0   clo=198row=195 k=0 
>   clo=199row=92 k=0  clo=199row=195 k=0  clo=200row=92 k=0
>   clo=200row=195 k=0     clo=201row=93 k=0   clo=201row=195 k=0 
>   clo=202row=94 k=0  clo=202row=195 k=0  clo=203row=95 k=0
>   clo=203row=195 k=0     clo=204row=95 k=0   clo=204row=195 k=0 
>   clo=205row=96 k=0  clo=205row=195 k=0  clo=206row=97 k=0
>   clo=206row=195 k=0     clo=207row=97 k=0   clo=207row=195 k=0 
>   clo=208row=98 k=0  clo=208row=195 k=0  clo=209row=99 k=0
>   clo=209row=195 k=0     clo=210row=100 k=0  clo=210row=195 k=0 
>   clo=211row=101 k=0     clo=211row=195 k=0  clo=212row=101 k=0 
>   clo=212row=195 k=0     clo=213row=102 k=0  clo=213row=195 k=0 
>   clo=214row=103 k=0     clo=214row=195 k=0  clo=215row=104 k=0 
>   clo=215row=195 k=0     clo=216row=105 k=0  clo=216row=195 k=0 
>   clo=217row=106 k=0     clo=217row=195 k=0  clo=218row=107 k=0 
>   clo=218row=195 k=0     clo=219row=108 k=0  clo=219row=195 k=0 
>   clo=220row=109 k=0     clo=220row=195 k=0  clo=221row=110 k=0 
>   clo=221row=195 k=0     clo=222row=111 k=0  clo=222row=195 k=0 
>   clo=223row=112 k=0     clo=223row=195 k=0  clo=224row=113 k=0 
>   clo=224row=195 k=0     clo=225row=195 k=0  clo=226row=195 k=0 
>   clo=227row=195 k=0     clo=228row=195 k=0  clo=229row=194 k=0 
>   clo=229row=195 k=0

Comment: use indents in the code and more spaces in the output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are going beyond the image bounds. You are unlucky that your application did not crash( would have made it much more evident). You have your loop incorrect. it should be < and not <=

```
for(i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
{
```

Comment: Thank you it work's. Now my code is giving me correct values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really used to OpenCV in C++ and I can't test it right now, but according to the documentation you should access a pixel's intensity like this:

`Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x);`

intensity.val[0] then contains the grey value from 0 to 255.

Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work , i haven’t tested it though

```
int k = (int)img.at<uchar>(j,i);
```